# Why would one want to study the geometry of Lie groups?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, education, topology

[Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) are commonly used in theoretical physics and mathematical physics. They are useful tools to study simple systems such as the harmonic oscillator. They are also crucial in representation theory (for example, the [Poincaré group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Poincar%C3%A9_group) for free relativistic particles). Thus, physicists and mathematicians are interested in studying their properties.

As a consequence, the geometry of Lie groups is well documented. For example, the geometry of $SU(2)$ is well known. We know that it can be represented by a $S^3$ sphere in $R^4$, we know its first fundamental form, we know its geodesics, etc.

In mathematics, we want to learn as much as we can from the objects that we are working with, so I understand the reasons why one would study the geometry of Lie groups. However, in physics, we want to use/apply those mathematical objects to "real" problems.
Hence my question: as physicists, why would we want to study the geometry of Lie groups?

I have done an advanced quantum mechanic course, and a differential geometry course. However, I haven't done a QFT course yet. My guess is that the geometry of Lie groups is used in that field. Any lead would help!

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: “We” don’t: it’s useful to less than 1% of working physicists.

Comment: Check out chapter 12 of Schwartz QFT book.